# How do I pause execution in Kotlin whilst APIs complete

Tags: android, api, rest, kotlin, asynchronous

I am trying to write a simple app in Android Studio using Kotlin. It is a very steep learning curve for me, but I am almost there. My final problem is getting the app to wait for the APIs to complete before moving the next Intent.

I have three calls each uploading data via my API. They are called from a button and only when the three are uploaded, should the button send the user to the next intent/screen.

My API calls are working and I can see the data in the database. However, since enqueue is asynchronous the calls are firing and the code is moving on the start the next intent before the data is present.

The code below is executed 3 times (once for each upload). I realise this is probably not the best way to do it, but I'm trying to get it working before I finesse the code.
I thought that perhaps I could have a variable, UploadedReadCount, that I increment in the onResponse, but this doesn't seem to be working properly.
Could someone offer some advice as to how I should be pausing the code until the APIs complete? For example, is there an enqueue methos that isn't async?

```
            ReadInterface.create().AddRead("new", rFuel, rRegister, rReadDate, rRead)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<UploadedRead> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadedRead>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Err: ", t.localizedMessage!!)
                    t.printStackTrace()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadedRead>, response: Response<UploadedRead>) {
                    Log.d("Response: ", response.body().toString())
                    val p = response.body()?.APIResult!![0]

                    msgShow("Gas read " + rRead.toString() + " uploaded")

                    UploadedReadCount += 1
                }
            })

        while ( UploadedReadCount < 3) {
            Log.d("Waiting ", UploadedReadCount.toString() + " reads uploaded...")
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, Billing::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("ReadDate", txtReadDate.text.toString())
        }

        startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Place your `Intent` and `startActivity(intent)` function in the callback : `onResponse` inside a `if(UploadedReadCount > count) {.. }` - or something of that nature. Key takeaway - react in the callback.  You could use coroutines to make async callbacks feel more like sequential code, but that's probably for another day..

Comment: The one I posted though is the 3rd call of 3. Can I safely assume that the onResponse for the 3rd call will be the last to complete?

Comment: If you have written  prior logic  sequentially i.e post1->onResponse->post2->onResponse->post3->onResponse-> trigger event, then yes.  You havent provided any logic or code to show how you "chain" api calls, if they are sequential its easy if they are parallel then you can place the count "latch" code in all 3 ressponse callbacks, you don't care which one triggers the event so long as all 3 api calls are complete.

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course. Thank you Mark. I have just repeated the block three times, so having the counter and call in each works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't want to pause execution while API call returns, Instead you want to follow the reactive model, that is when you call API you specify some callbacks (onResponse, onFailure), and once these callbacks are invoked then you react.

> code is moving on the start the next intent before the data is
> present.

Move all of your code that depends on data received from API in `onResponse` or `onFailure` methods (callbacks), When API is ready with some response one of those callbacks will be invoked and then depending on the data that you receive from API you can continue your work.

> is there an enqueue methos that isn't async?

There are options available to call an API in blocking manner but I don't think that is good idea. Instead of doing a blocking API call, you should try to do reactive programming that is as soon as any callback (onResponse, onFailure) is called only then you continue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to `enqueue` that is suspending instead of async, so you can call your code sequentially without blocking the main thread in a coroutine. The function is `await()` and it returns the successful result or throws an HttpException on failure.

But to run three requests in parallel, you need to use the `async` coroutine builder. This can be done by mapping a list of Calls to `async` calls that `await` the individual results, and then using `awaitAll()` on the list of Deferreds to wait for all three. So, it's more complicated than just running sequential code in a coroutine, but I think this is still easier than trying to run and wait for three parallel calls using callbacks.

I'm not exactly sure what your other two calls are so I'll just make up some and assume this function already has all the data it needs to make the calls. I also don't know how you want to handle failure, so I'm just making it stop early if any of the three calls fail.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val requests: List<Call<UploadedRead>> = listOf(
        ReadInterface.create().AddRead("new", rFuel, rRegister, rReadDate, rRead),
        ReadInterface.create().AddRead("new2", rFuel, rRegister, rReadDate, rRead),
        ReadInterface.create().AddRead("new3", rFuel, rRegister, rReadDate, rRead)
    )
    val responses: List<UploadedRead> = try {
        coroutineScope { // any failure in this block cancels them all
            requests.map { async { it.await() } } // run them simultaneously with async
                .awaitAll()
        }
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        Log.d("Err: ", e.localizedMessage.toString())
        printStackTrace(e)
        return@launch
    }

    // Do something with the list of three UploadedReads here.
}
```

I just duplicated the functionality of your code above, but it doesn't look like you're using the response for anything and you have an unused variable `p`.

Edit: If this is a pattern you use frequently, this helper function might be useful. I didn't check this thoroughly or test it.

```
/**
 * Await the result of all the Calls in parallel. Any exception thrown by any item
 * in the list will cancel all unfinished calls and be rethrown.
 */
suspend fun <T: Any> Iterable<Call<T>>.awaitAll(): List<T> = 
    coroutineScope { map { async { it.await } }.awaitAll() }


//...
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val requests: List<Call<UploadedRead>> = listOf(
        //...
    )
    val responses: List<UploadedRead> = try {
        requests.awaitAll()
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        //...
        return@launch
    }
    //...
}
```